# Azure DevOps Secure File Windows agent support

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Does Azure DevOps Services Secure Files and the Download Secure Files task for the Azure Pipeline support Windows Agents too?

[Secure Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/secure-files?view=azure-devops)

The technical documentation given in the Microsoft docs provides an example only for Linux agents and hence the question.

[Download Secure Files Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-secure-file?source=recommendations&view=azure-devops)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, "Download secure file" task works for Windows agents.

[image]

[image]

[image]